# Why cant i change the color of a button in react-native

Tags: react-native

"I want to change my two buttons color to RED and Green , But it doesn't change.Tried:Button  styles  and also 
          Button color="#0088000"> like this"

```
*< Card style={styles.cd}
        onPress={() => 
        alert('vishal')
        }
        onLongPress={() =>
        this.dialogComponent.show()
        }                     
>
 <Text style={styles.fil}>Approval request for {item.createdBy} :-: {item.titlePrefix}  </Text>
<View style={styles.containerB}>                 
       <Button 
            color="#0088000"
            title="Approve"
            onPress ={()=>alert("but1")}
          />        
        <Button            
            title="Reject"
            onPress ={()=>alert("but2")}
          />       
</View>     
     </Card >*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to remove one character of that value.

color="#0088000" =>  color="#088000" or color="red"

Enjoy react-native!